# Haskell `where` with pattern-matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, where-clause

I have such function:

```
eval :: Expr -> Either ArithmeticError Int
eval (Const a) = Right a
eval (Add a b) = liftM2 (+) ea eb
  where
    ea = eval a
    eb = eval b
eval (Sub a b) = liftM2 (-) ea eb
  where
    ea = eval a
    eb = eval b
```

I would like to rewrite this with one `where` usage. Can I do it? But pattern-matching should stay in this code. Thanks!

Comment: Why not make a helper function `_eval f a b = liftM2 f (eval a) (eval b)`, and then specify `eval (Add a b) = _eval (+) a b` and `eval (Sub a b) = _eval (-) a b`?

Comment: Or use `Data.Function.on`: ``eval (Add a b) = liftM2 (+) `on` eval``.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank for your recommendation. Yep, i know this approach, but I am looking for a way without another functions

Comment: @chepner looks beautiful. But what's wrong old `eval (Add a b) = liftM2 (+) (eval a) (eval b)`?

Comment: @Ismor Ask the OP; they are the one not writing that in the first place.

Comment: I have also such pattern 
```eval (Div a b) =
  liftM2
    div
    ea
    (eb >>=
     (\x ->
        if x == 0
          then Left DivisionByZero
          else Right x))
  where
    ea = eval a
    eb = eval b```

@chepner and `on` will not suitable for this case

Comment: Don't lift `div`; lift a safe-division function.

Comment: ``eval (Div a b) = liftM2 (\x y -> if y == 0 then Left DivisionByZero else Right (div x y)) `on` eval``

Comment: @chepner ``eval (Add a b) = liftM2 (+) `on` eval`` looks wrong to me, it's not using `a` nor `b`. Your last snippet also does not use `a` and `b`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that step. It would have to be something like ``eval (Add a b)= (liftM2 (+) `on` eval) a b``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no general, straightforward way of matching against patterns with common variables:

```
foo (Bar a b) = ...
foo (Baz a b) = ...
```

and then writing expressions (in `where` clauses or elsewhere) such that `a` and `b` correspond to both patterns simultaneously.  In Haskell, a pattern creates a new scope in which variables in the pattern are bound by that pattern, and there's no way to "combine" those bindings -- a usage of `a` or `b` will *either* refer to the bindings in `Bar a b` *or* `Baz a b`, never both.

About the best you can do is use a `case` statement to apply a common `where` clause to multiple patterns and make use of a common helper function that takes `a` and `b` as arguments and explicitly rebinds them to common names, on a pattern-by-pattern basis:

```
eval :: Expr -> Either ArithmeticError Int
eval e = case e of
  Const a -> Right a
  Add a b -> go (+) a b
  Sub a b -> go (-) a b

  where go op a b = liftM2 op (eval a) (eval b)
```